# Does cold water immersion at moderate temperatures like 20C inhibit strength and hypertrophy?

Tags: strength, hypertrophy, cold

It is well known that cold water immersion at more icy temperatures within 6 hours of working out will negate some or many of one’s muscular gains. Though apparently this doesn’t apply to cold showers that aren’t immersive. However how does this translate to more moderate temperate water immersion such as 15C or 20C?